# ¿Cómo contabilizar los días laborales (lunes a viernes) entre dos fechas de distinto mes en caso de querer separarlos por meses?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada *vacaciones*, donde se muestra el número de empleado junto con la fecha inicial y final de sus vacaciones:

| num_empleado | inicial | final |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 26/10/21 | 22/11/21 |

Lo que busco es visualizar la cantidad de días de vacaciones que tuvo cada empleado, pero separándolos por mes y sin tomar en cuenta los días inhábiles (sábados y domingos).

Por ejemplo, si quisiera visualizar las vacaciones del empleado **1001**, se debería desplegar lo siguiente:

| dias | mes |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 10 |
| 16 | 11 |

Tengo la siguiente *query* con la que he trabajado:

```sql
SELECT num_empleado,
       EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM t.Fecha ) as YearMonth,
       COUNT(1)                           as Dias
       FROM (select v.num_empleado,
                    DATE_ADD(v.inicial, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) as Fecha
                    FROM vacaciones v
                    CROSS JOIN seq_1_to_100 s
                       WHERE  DATE_ADD(v.inicial, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) <= v.final
                    ORDER BY v.num_empleado, , v.inicial, s.seq
        ) t
        GROUP BY num_empleado,
                 EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM t.Fecha )
```

Con la *query* anterior separo los días entre un rango de dos fechas con su respectivo mes pero, ¿cómo podría adaptar mi *query* para dejar de considerar los sábados y domingos? Estoy usando MariaDB 10.4 en phpMyAdmin. De antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He dado con la resupuesta para MySQL 5.7 y que adapta la *query* original descrita en la pregunta:

```sql
SELECT no_empleado, 
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.Date) AS ano, 
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.Date) AS mes, 
       SUM(WEEKDAY(`Fecha`) < 5) as Dias 
FROM (SELECT v.no_empleado, 
             DATE_ADD(v.inicial, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) AS Fecha 
FROM vacaciones v CROSS JOIN seq_1_to_100 s 
WHERE DATE_ADD(v.inicial, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) <= v.final 
ORDER BY v.no_empleado, v.inicial, s.seq ) t 
GROUP BY no_empleado, EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM t.Fecha);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo he utilizado una query recursiva para generar los días entre la fecha inicial y la fecha final de las vacaciones.

Luego utilizo la función `DAYOFWEEK()` para determinar de que día de la semana se trata, solo tengo en cuenta de lunes a viernes (en este caso los feriados se estarían contabilizando como días laborales si caen entre un lunes y un viernes).

Agrupo por empleado, año y mes ya que asumo que las vacaciones podrían ser que empiecen un año y terminen otro año (ej: de mediados de diciembre a mediados de enero); y cuento la cantidad de días de semana (de lunes a viernes).

Tengo en cuenta que cada empleado se habrá tomado varias veces vacaciones en distintos periodos (que son excluyentes).

```
WITH RECURSIVE dias_vac AS (SELECT num_empleado, inicial AS dia
                            FROM vacaciones
                       
                            UNION ALL
                        
                            SELECT dv.num_empleado, DATE_ADD(dv.dia, INTERVAL 1 day)
                            FROM dias_vac dv
                            INNER JOIN vacaciones v ON dv.num_empleado = v.num_empleado AND dv.dia BETWEEN v.inicial AND DATE_ADD(v.final, INTERVAL -1 day))
                       
SELECT num_empleado, YEAR(dia) AS `Año`, MONTH(dia) AS Mes, count(*) AS `Días`
FROM dias_vac
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(dia) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
GROUP BY num_empleado, YEAR(dia), MONTH(dia);
```

**Salida** con los datos de ejemplo de la pregunta:

| num_empleado | Año | Mes | Días |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2021 | 10 | 4 |
| 1001 | 2021 | 11 | 16 |

Comment: Me parece una excelente aportación, muchas gracias; desgraciadamente, haciendo pruebas e investigando un poco, leí que los CTE (WITH) sí los acepta MariaDB, pero tiene bugs de paginación (tarda mucho al generar la consulta). Más información aquí: github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/issues/165
¿Cómo se adaptaría ese *query* para **MySQL 5.x**?

Comment: De nada @JorgeDuran!!! Según tu enlace el problema es con phpmyadmin (no con MariaDB). Si no quieres utilizar CTE en MariaDB lo puedes hacer con una secuencia (como lo haces en la pregunta), y en MySql 5.x hay varias formas de resolverlo, una puede ser utilizar un procedimiento para generar los días o "imitar" la solución de la secuencia (hay varias preguntas en que resuelven dicho problema).